Pulsar Initialization in Docker Composition
I'd like to have a single docker-compose.yaml file for starting my development environment. In the Docker composition I have a Pulsar container:
version: '3.8'
services:
  pulsar:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 6650:6650
    environment:
      PULSAR_MEM: " -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1g"
    volumes:
      - pulsardata:/pulsar/data
      - pulsarconf:/pulsar/conf
    command: bin/pulsar standalone
volumes:
  pulsardata:
  pulsarconf:

I'd like to create a tenant abc and a namespace nnn under abc. and found out that the Pulsar image doesn't give some out of the box way to do so. Any idea how can I achieve this in a single docker-compose.yaml file?
Thanks!
all suggestions that I encountered involve running some docker exec command after container is up.

version: '3.5'
networks:
pulsar:
driver: bridge
services:
Start zookeeper
pulsar:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:4.0.0
    container_name: pulsar
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"
    - "6650:6650"
    environment:
        PULSAR_MEM: " -Xms256m -Xmx256m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m"
        systemTopicEnabled: "true"
        topicLevelPoliciesEnabled: "true"
        transactionCoordinatorEnabled: "true"
    command: bash -c "bin/apply-config-from-env.py conf/standalone.conf && bin/pulsar standalone"

